# SharePoint Document's Library metadata duplicates after REST call

Tags: ajax, typescript, sharepoint

I am making a POST ajax request to a SharePoint Document Library folder to save a file along with some metadata. The file and the metadata are saved correctly however, the metadata are sometimes(not all the time) replicated inside the document library(where I place folder not files). **Why does this happen?** ***How can I prevent this from happening?*** Here is a code snippet of the ajax call:

```
    var result = $.ajax(
          {
             url: siteUrl.concat("/lists/getbytitle('")
            .concat("Document Library Name")
            .concat("')/RootFolder/folders('")
            .concat("Folder Name")
            .concat("')/files/add(url = '").concat(fileName).concat("', overwrite = true)"),
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
            },
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
            },
            async: false
          });
```

Comment: Might be re-post your request if press F5.

Comment: @Lee_MSFT, I don't think it is a repost because it sends the same data once but to 2 different places.